# Spring URL pattern throwing 404 Error Status Code

Tags: spring, web-services

request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.do").forward(request,response);
` request which am trying

web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>user</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:springContext/dataSource.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>user</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Request passing:
 request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.do").forward(request,response);

Controller Code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login.do", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public String login() {
```

Anyone have any suggestions

URL pattern is not able to find the correct path.Tried all possible combination.

Comment: sorry typo error.it is getallusers only

Comment: When you start the Spring application, with DEBUG logging on the Spring packages, it will tell you the mapped URLs.

Comment: could not find anything from logs.any other suggestions